# RTCError: Rejected data channel transport with mid=0

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm trying to set up a data channel connection between two peers with webrtc but am running into this issue on the peer creating the offer.

This is the full RCTErrorEvent object that i'm getting from the `onerror` callback on the data channel i've created:
[image]

This error is getting thrown when the answering client sends this SDP message back:

```
v=0
o=- 4032937039670154216 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=application 0 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=mid:0
a=sctp-port:5000
```

Any idea how I can resolve this issue, or what mid=0 even means?

Edit:
This is what the offer SDP looks like:

```
v=0
o=- 1617373214565242991 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:qoYs
a=ice-pwd:JS3NDg62V+cpJRUhEBSbMVcq
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 7A:C5:F6:CB:C0:94:44:12:22:C5... (removed)
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=sctp-port:5000
a=max-message-size:262144
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `m=application 0 ...` in your SDP. This means the datachannel protocol is *not* negotiated. That does not happen normally, are you doing anything special to the SDP?

Comment: I add the SDP offer to the post, we manually needed to remove `a=extmap-allow-mixed\r\n` from offer SDP for our other peer to accept it. Also the peer sending the offer SDP is a Chrome browser running javascript. The peer sending the answer SDP is C++ application running on a ubuntu server.

Comment: does that server use the now-removed "rtp datachannels"? The protocol is incompatible to the standard SCTP ones.